# How to do the multi Button onPress functions in one common component - React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component call **ButtonLayout.js**

```
export const ButtonLayout = () => {
return (
    <View style={styles.row}>

         <TouchableOpacity >
             <Text>Book Now</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>

         <TouchableOpacity >
             <Text>Schedule</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>

)
}
```

and i have import this component to another common component called **mapComponent**   and it look like following.

```
return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                style={styles.map}
                region={this.props.region}
            >
                <MapView.Marker
                    coordinate={this.props.region}
                    pinColor='green'
                />
            </MapView>

            <ButtonLayout style={{ marginBottom: 5 }} />

        </View>

    );
```

so my question is how can i handle the **onPress()** function of the buttons in **ButtonLayout.js** from **index.js** ?

Comment: Pass onpress callback/s to your `ButtonLayout` in your index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your ButtonLayout component accept callback props, like so:

```
export const ButtonLayout = ({onBook, onSchedule}) => (
    <View style={styles.row}>

     <TouchableOpacity onPress={onBook}>
         <Text>Book Now</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>

     <TouchableOpacity onPress={onSchedule}>
         <Text>Schedule</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>

</View>);
```

Then, pass the callbacs in the parent component’s render function as props

```
<ButtonLayout onBook={…} onSchedule={…} />
```

Don’t forget to bind the context to the callbacks

Answer (score 0):

In your button `Buttonlayout.js` define like this:

```
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.onPress()}>
         <Text>Book Now</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
```

And define `onPress` function on each file you use this component just like.

```
<ButtonLayout style={{ marginBottom: 5 }} onPress={() => {'your logic..'}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your callback variables in `ButtonLayout` and add them to your touchables.

```
export const ButtonLayout = ({ onBookPress, onSchedulePress }) => {
return (
    <View style={styles.row}>

         <TouchableOpacity onPress={onBookPress}>
             <Text>Book Now</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>

         <TouchableOpacity onPress={onSchedulePress} >
             <Text>Schedule</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>

)
}
```

Define your callbacks in index:

```
indexOnBookPress = () => {
 ...do something
}

indexOnSchedulePress = () => {
 ...do something
}
return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MapView
                    provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                    style={styles.map}
                    region={this.props.region}
                >
                    <MapView.Marker
                        coordinate={this.props.region}
                        pinColor='green'
                    />
                </MapView>
                <ButtonLayout style={{ marginBottom: 5 }} onBookPress={this.indexOnBookPress} onSchedulePress={this.indexOnSchedulePress} />
            </View>
        );
```